# What are words called that share the same root?

Tags: terminology, roots

What do you call words that share the same root (e.g., "network", "networks", "networking"). Also, does the shortest one of them have a specific name (e.g., "network")?

Comment: Smart-alek kids quickly came up with
co-etymological
and
iso-original
and then things got silly 8-)

Answer (score 6):

I would call *network* a ["stem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_stem), *networks* (noun or verb) an "inflected form", *networking* (participle) an "inflected form", and *networking* (noun) a "derived term".

"Root" is not the same as "stem" in my book; *network* has two roots, *net* and *work*.

Comment: As to the general term for all words that share the same root, I have no idea. In Russian, they are called "related words", but in English, that means [something different](http://www.merriam-webster.com/help/thesnotes/related-words.htm).

Comment: Of course, words that share the same *derivational* root (usually in different languages) would be called [cognates](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/cognate_1) - not really what's being asked for here but I mention it because someone searching for that meaning would likely find this question.

Comment: @psmears: that really should be an official answer.

Answer (score 2):

A set of words that can be grouped together is called a ***[word family](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/dick/tta/wf/wf.htm)***.  A word family can be *form-based* or *meaning-based*.  The question describes a *form-based* word family and the shortest form is sometimes a *root*, however, I agree with RegDwight's answer that the word *network* is composed of two roots.

> Form-based families are important because they reveal sometimes hidden patterns of spelling in words that children already know; for example, the verb root pronounced 'seev' is spelt ceive (receive, deceive, conceive), and always corresponds to ception in the corresponding noun (reception, deception, conception).
>
> Meaning-based families are important because they reveal links and patterns of meaning in words that children already know; for example, many adjectives and nouns are related as in the trio big - little - size. The specific meaning relations they contain (see below) are also an important component of reasoning skills.

Comment: This is correct as far as it goes, but "word family" is not a standard term. It sounds like a grade school textbook explanation trying not to use big words like _semantic_ and _historical_ and _cognate_.

Comment: @JohnLawler It may not be a standard term but I don't think it's fair to label it "grade school textbook", given that it was published in the International Journal of Lexicography.  http://www.victoria.ac.nz/lals/about/staff/publications/paul-nation/1993-Bauer-Word-families.pdf

Answer (score 2):

In linguistics, words that share a common etymology are called **cognates**.  [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cognate) gives this definition:

> 3a :  related by descent from the same ancestral language

Cognates can be in the same language or two different languages.  [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cognate) provides these examples:

> English *mother* is cognate with Greek *μητέρα* ‎(mitéra), German *Mutter*, Russian *мать* ‎(matʹ) and Persian *مادر* ‎(madar).
>
> English *shirt* is cognate with English *skirt*, *short*, and *curt* ... all of these are descended from the Proto-Indo-European root *(s)ker-*, meaning ‘to cut’.